# Set Text Value of Lookup Using Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use javascript to set the text value in a lookup field in CRM when creating a new form.

I am using Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm and use the following code:

```js
var parameters = {};
parameters['myLookupFieldNameID'] = '{LookupGuidHere}'; //This is the value of the lookup being passed in
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(sEntityName, null, parameters);
```

And when the page loads, if I save it, it is setting the value correctly, but when the form opens, it is not actually showing the name value of that field. Is there any way to pass that in using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just set the ID for a lookup using javascript or parameters, it will still work, but CRM doesn't automatically go get the name for you - you need to pass that in as well. See documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334375.aspx#BKMK_setValueLookupfields

Comment: Thanks,
I am leaving work now, but I will look into this on Monday and let you know how it turns out

Comment: Worked perfetly! Thanks, I dug and dug but couldn't find this, it is greatly appreciated